# fsockopen connection does not close until timeout

Tags: php, fgets, fsockopen

**Background**:
I have to create a plain site that accepts incoming posted XML and sends the XML to a server via a socket connection and in turn display the XML sent back from the server. Easy peasy.

**Problem**:
I had no problem utilising *fsockopen()* to connect to the server and sending the XML. Reading the XML from the server was a whole new problem. The normal

```
while (!feof($fp)) {    
    echo fgets($fp);
}
```

did not do the trick, since the server returns one XML string, and one XML string only (no length information, eof, eol, etc.). Thus it would wait until the timeout was hit, display the received XML and a timeout error. My problem is similar to this [dinosaur](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/4527-problems-using-fsockopen-stream_set_timeout-fgets).

In a nutshell I want to read XML on the socket and close it as soon as no more data is being sent (not wait for timeout). Setting the timeout to a low value was also not viable as the server response can vary between 2--30 seconds.

**Solution**:
After struggling for the entire afternoon I decided to share the following solution for this problem (do criticise).

```
$fp = fsockopen("123.456.789.1", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)";
} else {
    $wait = true;    
    $out = '<samplexml><item>something</item></samplexml>';

    // [1] disable blocking
    stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);
    fwrite($fp, $out);

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $r = fgets($fp);
        echo $r;
        if (!strcmp($r, "")){                
            if (!$wait) {
                // [2] has recieved data on this socket before
                break;
            }
        } else {
            $wait = false;
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

It turns out that my main problem was *blocking*. So first off, [1] I had to disable stream_set_blocking so that *fgets()* can continuously check if new data became available. If not disabled *fgets()* will get the XML from the server and then the loop will get stuck on the second try since it will wait until more data becomes available (which never will).

I know that as soon as we have read some data that we can immediatly close the connection if any empty *fgets()* are returned (thus we can still set the second parameter of *fgets()* if it should be necessary).

After using this site for months I **finally** got to post something on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hang on, if you already have a solution, why are you posting the question here?

Comment: seems like the typical solution... non blocking read socket... wait for eof or socket disconnection.

Comment: @ricosrealm it's not _that_ typical, since I don't get a eof nor do I want to wait for a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet has several problems:

- First, the comparison `strcmp($r, "")` doesn't actually make sense. It works, but it doesn't make sense. I don't think [`fgets`](http://php.net/fgets) ever returns an empty string. If there is no more data available, it returns *`FALSE`*. The reason your comparison works is that `FALSE` is converted to an empty string. But it makes your code not clear.
- Second, since you have the stream in non-blocking mode, data can be not available only temporarily. By breaking from the loop as soon as `fgets` returns false, you're potentially reading only the first batch of data that was cached by the OS. You try to work around this by forcing a wait no data has been received yet, but it's a brittle solution.
- Finally, you busy loop waiting for the data. This is very resource intensive.

The two last points can be solved by using [`stream_select`](http://php.net/stream_select). This way you can enforce a large timeout until the first packet is received and then use a small timeout.

Comment: Cool, I made a mistake there with fgets(), will fix that. I will definitely give stream_select a look (looks exactly like what I need).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`fread()`](http://php.net/fread) and pull in a single byte at a time. Very inefficient, but you could then parse the response as it comes and detect when the XML ends without having to wait for the connection to time out. In hacky pseudo-code:

```
while(true) {
    $char = fread($fp, 1);
    $xml .= $char;
    if (is_complete($xml)) {
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just realised that I can go without the (!feof($fp)) check and replace it with (true) - a needless improvement but an improvement nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I use the socket. I send a xml string and I receive a xml string too. When the server sends me the string `'</response>'`, I must to close the socket. In the following you can find my code, if that can help someone:

```
            stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);
            fwrite($fp, $in);
            $result = '';

            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $r = fgets($fp);
                $result .= $r;
                //echo $r;
                if (strstr($r, "</response>") != null)
                    break;
            }
            fclose($fp);
```